# Log4net log to Azure Storage Account

Tags: .net, azure, log4net, azure-storage

I have an Azure storage account that I would like to log to from my Web API project which is using Log4Net and is hosted in a App Service. Is this possible? I have seen several posts for setting up Log4Net logging with Azure but they are either a few years old or recommend using a Nuget package (Log4Net Azure Appender) which also seems to be out of date using older dependencies. Any recommendations or approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the NuGet packages you already found. Or write your own log4net appender if you can't find something you like.

[log4netBlobStorageAppender](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4netBlobStorageAppender/)